# how to store data to be used in the callback in ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

user can assign multiple predefined `events` to a `room` however, sometimes they might create new `events` on the fly.

I want to capture these new events and add them to a separate table `userevent`

Below is my approach. I am trying to save all the events that don't exist into a `:user_events` and then callback `add_new_events_to_userevents`  on after_save.

```
  after_save :add_new_events_to_userevents
  attr_reader :event_tokens, :user_events 
  attr_accessible :user_events #not real column in table
  attr_accessible :fulladdress, :title, :description, :cost, :email, :maximum_capacity, :phone, :user_id, :property_id

  def add_new_events_to_userevents
    print "total new events:" + self.user_events.size
    self.user_events.each do |i| 
      u = Userevent.new
      u.name = i
      u.approved = false
      u.room_id = self.id
      u.user_id = self.user_id
      u.save
    end
  end

  def event_tokens=(ids)
    events = ids.split(',')
    allowed_events = []
    userevents = []
    events.each do |i|
      i = i.strip
      events = Event.select(:id).where("upper(name) = ?", i.upcase);
      event = (events.blank? ? nil : events.first)
      if event.present?
        allowed_events << event[:id]
      else
        userevents << i
      end
    end
    self.event_ids = allowed_events #these are events that exist
    self.user_events = userevents #these are new events, need them in after_save
  end
```

I am getting an error

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.size
```

- how can I store all new user events and then use them in my `after_save` callback?
- in the `after_save` callback if I call `self.id` and `self.user_id` will that give me `id` and `user_id` of the record that was just saved to the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the line with the print statement breaks if you don't have user_events defined for a user...
add an if-statement to it to make it work..

```
print "total new events:" + self.user_events.size   if user_events
```

Comment: well that will fix the error however, I still can't get the user_events to get saved.

Comment: well, if you got the error about a nil object, that means that self.user_events was nil ... e.g. there _are_no_ user_events for some other reason... can you double-check with a valid example where you know that there should be user_events defined for that user?

Comment: I've checked that. I wish to know whether the technique I am using (saving `user_events` in a `self` variable and then using that variable in `after_save` method is the best way to go